# Extract hours as 1 - 48 from half hour interval times

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have the below data.

```
0:00:00
0:30:00
1:00:00
1:30:00
2:00:00
2:30:00
3:00:00
3:30:00
4:00:00
4:30:00
5:00:00
5:30:00
6:00:00
6:30:00
```

I can extract the hour the using `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP)` but this will give me 24 hours.

But now I need to some different calculation where I can get numbers from `1-48` based on the time given.

Something like this:

```
0:00:00 1
0:30:00 2
1:00:00 3
1:30:00 4
2:00:00 5
2:30:00 6
3:00:00 7
3:30:00 8
4:00:00 9
4:30:00 10
6:00:00 13
6:30:00 14
```

Note the skipped 11 and 12, for the absent values 5:00 and 5:30.

Is there any possibilities that I can get that result in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's possible with a `left outer join` over a `generate_series` from the min to the max time, with `INTERVAL '30' MINUTE` as the value spacing (3rd arg), but it won't be particularly pretty. I'd probably `extract(epoch from my_time)` and use modulus/division instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I got it now. Will give it a try :). But one help. How can I generate both time and number in just one generate_series query?

Comment: Add that as a answer. I'll accept it. I got through this because of your idea. Thanks again.

Comment: What should happen, if the input is f.ex. `7:24:31` or `8:15:00`?

Comment: No. Data will not be like that in my case. It'll be only in a difference of 30 mins. `0:00`, `0:30`, `1:00` like this.

Comment: Do you have `time` or `interval` data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use formula **`1 + extract(hour from 2 * tm)`** - it gives your expected result exactly - obligatory [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a193d/1).

Comment: Simple and amazing :). Just wondering why I didn't think in that way.

Comment: +1, but maybe worth mentioning that this will only work with intervals (not with times, nor timestamps), which aren't justified & has only hour, minute and second parts only http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/13ab6/1

Comment: For such weird intervals, you can use `1 + (extract(epoch from tm)/1800)::int`. Idea is to convert interval to seconds and divide it by 1800 (which is 30 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a `double precision` result, that you can round to whatever you want:

```
2 * (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t) / 60) + 1
```

**EDIT**:

Or, as @CraigRinger suggested:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t) / 1800 + 1
```

For the later, `t` needs to be `TIME`, **not** `TIMESTAMP`. Use cast if needed.
**UPDATE**: This will work with `INTERVAL`s too.

```
SELECT 2 * (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t) / 60) + 1,
       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t) / 1800 + 1
FROM (VALUES (time '4:30:00'), (time '7:24:31'), (time '8:15:00')) as foo(t)

-- results:

?column? | ?column?
---------+---------
10       | 10
15.8     | 15.8172222222222
17.5     | 17.5
```

But as you wrote, there will be no edge cases (when the time cannot be divided with 30 minutes).

Comment: Will give it a try and check.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
case 
when date_time_field_of_interest::time >= '00:00:00' and date_time_field_of_interest::time < '00:30:00' then 1 
when date_time_field_of_interest::time >= '00:30:00' and date_time_field_of_interest::time < '01:00:00' then 2  
....
end 
from your_table;
```

Comment: for 48 cases? Case has its uses, but I don't think this is one of them.